# Is it possible to fill in all the tabs and spaces with a color

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to fill in the tabs,and background tabs, with an rgb color, like so

[image: Example]

I want to do my tabs like the one on the right, where it's all one color,

The following code I have:

```
// Get the item from the collection.
TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

// Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
{

    // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
    _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 66,78,90));
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
}
else
{
    _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
    e.DrawBackground();
}
```

I have set the tabs to draw mode, how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Why draw yourself and not simply set the background color?

Comment: There's not option for me to set the background colo

Comment: WinForms is not recommended if you want complete control over the UI. You should use WPF instead.

Comment: it's a duplicated post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338587/set-tabpage-header-color?noredirect=1&lq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849801/c-sharp-winform-how-to-set-the-base-color-of-a-tabcontrol-not-the-tabpage

Comment: Not a duplicate, this post specifically says the whole background too, not just the tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can change the BackColor attribute of a tab: 
_tabPage.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;